# Scheme - do iterative - return value

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, iteration

I trying to write a function which gets an integer number ,  represented by string , and check if all his chars are digits and return `#t` \ `#f` accordingly . Thats the code  -

```
(define (splitString str) (list->vector (string->list str)))

(define myVector 0)
(define flag #t)

(define (checkIfStringLegal str) (
(set! myVector (splitString str))
(do (  (i 0 (+ i 1))  )  ; init
  ((= i (vector-length myVector)) flag) ; stop condition
  (cond ((>= 48 (char->integer (vector-ref myVector i)) ) (set! flag #f))
        ((<= 57 (char->integer (vector-ref myVector i)) )(set! flag #f))


  )    
)
) 
)
```

Few explanations  -

`(list->vector (string->list str))` - convert string the char list  .

`(vector-ref myVector i)` - char from the `myVector` at place `i` .

Its run OK   , but when I try to use this func  , like `(checkIfStringLegal "444")` I get  -

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: #<void>
  arguments...:
   #t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define (checkIfStringLegal str)
  (andmap char-numeric?
          (string->list str)))
```

This is how the procedure works:

1. It transforms the string into a list of characters, using `string->list`
2. It validates each character in the list to see if it's a number, applying the predicate `char-numeric?` to each one
3. If all the validations returned `#t`, `andmap` will return `#t`. If a single validation failed, `andmap` will return `#f` immediately

That's a functional-programming solution (and after all, this question is tagged as such), notice that your intended approach looks more like a solution in a C-like programming language - using vectors, explicit looping constructs (`do`), mutation operations (`set!`), global mutable definitions ... that's fine and it might eventually work after some tweaking, but it's not the idiomatic way to do things in Scheme, and it's not even remotely a functional-programming solution.

**EDIT:**

Oh heck, I give up. If you want to write the solution your way, this will work - you had a parenthesis problem, and please take good notice of the proper way to indent and close parenthesis in Scheme, it will make your code more readable for you and for others:

```
(define (splitString str) (list->vector (string->list str)))
(define myVector 0)
(define flag #t)

(define (checkIfStringLegal str)
  (set! myVector (splitString str))
  (do ((i 0 (+ i 1)))
    ((= i (vector-length myVector)) flag)
    (cond ((>= 48 (char->integer (vector-ref myVector i)))
           (set! flag #f))
          ((<= 57 (char->integer (vector-ref myVector i)))
           (set! flag #f)))))
```

Even so, the code could be further improved, I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader:

- Both conditions can be collapsed into a single condition, using an `or`
- The exit condition should be: end the loop when the end of the vector is reached *or* the flag is false

Comment: thats would work on integer , but I have also other requirements to check on this number  . So how can I solve it with my own code ?

Comment: @URL87 embrace functional programming! "when in Rome...". Just tweak the predicate until it meets your requirements. For example, if you have to test if it's a number _or_ a decimal dot, use this in place of `char-numeric?`: `(lambda (c) (or (char-numeric? c) (char=? c #\.)))`

Comment: I tried your 1st suggestion with `(checkIfStringLegal "444")`  , but it promped  `andmap: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier`

Comment: @URL87 it means that your interpreter doesn't have an `andmap` procedure. Here, use this: `(define (andmap pred lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) #t)
        ((not (pred (car lst))) #f)
        (else (andmap pred (cdr lst)))))`

Comment: @URL87 Be aware that the "real" [`andmap`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._andmap%29%29) behaves a little different, but my short implementation will work for what you need.